# what is the best method of smoothing time series for product share data?

Tags: time-series, smoothing

I am having a share data for products presribed over period of time.The share is calculated like for 3 products each one 1/3 share and like that,where products may vary and hence their share. What is the best method of optimal smoothing for these shares?

Comment: Very limited information in your question, you need to provide little more  details if you want a response.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable in the generality you are asking. Try something, see if it works. [Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp) is a good start.

Comment: Here are some things you might want to clarify. If you have 3 products, why are you expecting the shares to be equal (1/3)? How do the products vary? Are there new products that come into the market and others that disappear? Do you have a time series (e.g. one store with product shares across time) or a cross sectional time series (e.g. many stores with product shares for each store across time).  And, most importantly, what is the purpose of the smoothing?  Is it to forecast? Is it to provide a more stable estimate of the current market situation than the most recent period? Or...?

Comment: Its like this, if a doctor presribed 5 total products in week 1, then share of products, say A,B,C,D,E is equal i.e. 1/5. if the prescription is like A,A,B,C,C then share will be A:2/5,B:1/5,C:2/5,D:0,E:0 and like that for each physician each week.So we take weighted average of share of each product for each week, to produce share for that product for that week. The purpose of smoothing is that clients use them in forecasting models for providing stable estimate as per your last comment.